# Authors in JSS template for Rticles are superimposed, don't know how to put them in two lines

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I am trying to write a manuscript for the Journal of Statistical Software (JSS) and I have four authors, the problem is that when I knit the manuscript the affiliation of the authors is superimposed. I have seen that in [Articles with many authors](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v074i02) in JSS they put them in two lines, but I haven't found any way of doing that in the package Rticles, this is an example manuscript with 4 authors.

````
---
author:
  - name: Main author
    affiliation: University of life and more
    address: >
      First line
      Second line
    email: me@university.edu
    url: http://rstudio.com
  - name: second author
    affiliation: University of life and more
  - name: Third Author
    affiliation: University of life and more
  - name: Fourth Author
    affiliation: University of life and more
    title:
  formatted: "super interesting r package called \\pkg{TheSuperPackage}"
  short:     "\\pkg{TheSuperPackage}: This is exiting"
abstract: >
  We present a package that will solve your life
keywords:
  # at least one keyword must be supplied
  formatted: [ "\\pkg{TheSuperPackage}", Life, "\\proglang{R}"]
  plain:     [keywords, not capitalized, life]
preamble: >
  \usepackage{amsmath}
biblio-style: jss
output:
  rticles::jss_article:
    fig_caption: true
    citation_package: natbib
bibliography: Derek.bib
---


```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(rticles)
library(rmarkdown)
library(yaml)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(prompt=TRUE)
options(replace.assign=TRUE, width=90, prompt="R> ")
```

# Introduction

This template demonstrates some of the basic latex you'll need to know to create a JSS article.
````

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am experiencing the same problem in 2023.

Answer (score 0):

You can break the authors field into two lines by inserting the LaTeX keyword `\AND` in the affiliation field of the author before the break. To this end, you need to wrap the affiliation field in apostrophes e.g. `'affiliation: 'University of life and more \AND'`. The result will look like this:

[image: Header of JSS paper with four authors and break after the second]

Here is a working minimal example:

````
---
documentclass: jss
author:
  - name: Main author
    affiliation: University of life and more
    address: >
      First line
      Second line
    email: me@university.edu
    url: http://rstudio.com
  - name: second author
    affiliation: 'University of life and more \AND'
  - name: Third Author
    affiliation: University of life and more
  - name: Fourth Author
    affiliation: University of life and more
title:
  formatted: "super interesting r package called \\pkg{TheSuperPackage}"
  short:     "\\pkg{TheSuperPackage}: This is exiting"
abstract: >
  We present a package that will solve your life
keywords:
  # at least one keyword must be supplied
  formatted: [ "\\pkg{TheSuperPackage}", Life, "\\proglang{R}"]
  plain:     [keywords, not capitalized, life]
preamble: >
  \usepackage{amsmath}
biblio-style: jss
output:
  rticles::jss_article
---


```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(rticles)
library(rmarkdown)
library(yaml)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(prompt=TRUE)
options(replace.assign=TRUE, width=90, prompt="R> ")
```

# Introduction

This template demonstrates some of the basic latex you'll need to know to create a JSS article.
````